# Woking with Packed Arrays, accessing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, pack

I'm working with a large image array, so i've packed it.  To access the pixels in the array i've implemented two methods.

```
def get_p(a)
  data=a.unpack('S9s')
end
def put_p(array,index_a,value)
  index=index_a[0]
  k=array.unpack('S9s')
  k[index]=value
  k.pack('S9s')
end
```

It works, but i wondered if there was a more elegant way to do this.  Makes my code look different than my standard array functions.

```
If get_p(image_data[i][j+1])[BLOB]==0
```

vs

```
if image_data[i][j+1][BLOB]==0
```

Also, don't know if anyone cares, but unpack doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, i was lucky to find a reference here, but it took some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could craete a class like:

```
class PackedArray

  def initialize(array)
    @packed_array = array.pack('S9s')
  end

  def [](key)
    data = @packed_array.unpack('S9s')
    data[key]
  end

  def []=(key, val)
    k = @packed_array.unpack('S9s')
    k[key]=val
    @packed_array = k.pack('S9s')
  end
end
```

Then, fill your `image_data[i][j]` with an instance of this class. E.g.

```
for i in [0..image_data.size]
  for j in [0..image_data[i].size]
    image_data[i][j] = new PackedArray(image_data[i][j])  
  end
end
```

And finally you can simply use:

```
if image_data[i][j+1][BLOB] == 0
```

Without needing of packing/unpacking manually.

Comment: Nice, much cleaner, i'll try it out tomorrow

Comment: Okay, I finally got back to this.  It took a while to find all the places i was packing/unpacking and fix them.  But this work excellently.  I wound up doing the init like this
       @image_data=Array.new(rows){Array.new(columns,PackedArray.new)}
  And i initialized like so.
    def initialize
      array=Array.new(CHANNELS,0)
      @packed_array=array.pack('S9s')
    end  

but all in all the code is much tighter and cleanner

Comment: Thought i'd mention that when i did the change i got bit by the aliasing defect since a assignment to array element was not to an object.  So my first clean pass created an array of mxn all pointing to the same object:).  I was assigning the element to a PackedArray object without using dup to insure that it was a copy.